# Unable to grab links out of some xml content from a webpage

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to scrape different links out of some xml content from a webpage but I get nothing as result when I execute the following script.

***What possible rectification should I bring about to produce the result?***

[website link](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/SiteMap1.xml)

A scatterted chunk of such xml containing a link:

```
<loc>
    https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/163666-REG/Rosco_150053860016_Off_Broadway_Paint.html
</loc>
```

My try (the script doesn't produce any result, nor throw any error):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.bhphotovideo.com/SiteMap1.xml'

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"xml")
for item in soup.select("url loc"):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, works for me too.

Comment: same here. works for me

Comment: I reran the above script to make sure it is working in my end as well but unfortunately I'm still getting nothing. It appears to be working but no result are there in the console. So weird!!!

Comment: Only thing I can think of trying is check version and/or reinstall/upgrade beautifulsoup4, lxml, etc Not sure what else you could do

Comment: Works fine for me. You could try using `lxml`, e.g.`soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")`. You might need to install it first.